# What can you do with leftover corn husks?

Tags: culinary-uses, mexican-cuisine, corn

We made tamales today, and had a lot of corn husks left over. Any suggestions on how they can be used?

Comment: To community members: if you consider voting to close, please make sure you are aware of our [policy on culinary-uses](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-culinary-uses-questions) before making your decision whether to cast a vote.

Comment: Corn husk dolls or other "crafty" projects (if the use need not be culinary in nature.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Options:

**Traditional**: line the bottom of the tamale steamer basket with them.

**Modern**: Steam something else in them, [like halibut](https://www.latimes.com/recipe/halibut-steamed-in-corn-husks).

**Marie Kondo**: Compost them.

Comment: Do they spark joy @FuzzyChef?

Comment: You can use corn husks as a base for smoking. See e.g. [Ottolenghi's smoked corn salad](https://ottolenghi.co.uk/recipes/bourbon-glazed-spare-ribs-with-smoked-corn-salad).

Comment: I like composting things as my compost turns back into food in the veg garden :-) Husks would also seem to make good earthworm bedding if one has a worm farm. Also, the (cooked then cooled) cobs seem to be a good fattening/multiplying food for them. Websearches should return a few more in and out of kitchen uses, e.g. [https://www.ruralsprout.com/corn-husks/](https://www.ruralsprout.com/corn-husks/).

Comment: I compost them, even though I'm not much of a Kondo fan. They spark joy in my compost pile.

Comment: They could be swapped for banana leaves in many applications, wrapping rice or steaming dim sum for example.